# Typechecking not working for generic string keys in Luau?

Tags: types, lua, roblox, typechecking, luau

I'm trying to create a dictionary data structure that contains several `CustomType` objects that can be associated with any string key.

I figured I could just use `{[string]: CustomType}` as my dictionary type, like this:

```
--!strict
type CustomType = {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

local dictionary: {[string]: CustomType} = {
    keyOne = { a = 'hello' }, -- should display type error ('b' field missing)
    keyTwo = { a = 'hello', b = 'world'} -- should be fine
}
```

However, in the code snippet above no type error is shown in the code editor even though the `b` field is missing from `keyOne`. Yet, if I explicitly define the keys in the dictionary type definition, then it works as expected:

```
--!strict
type CustomType = {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

local dictionary: {keyOne: CustomType, keyTwo: CustomType} = {
    keyOne = { a = 'hello' }, -- displays type error
    keyTwo = { a = 'hello', b = 'world'} -- is fine
}
```

Why is this? **I would like to enforce strict typechecking for all generic string keys without needing to explicitly define them in the dictionary type definition.** Am I going about this the wrong way? Could this be a ROBLOX issue (since I am implementing this in the ROBLOX engine)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Source/info about Luau typechecking: https://luau-lang.org/typecheck

Comment: I remember having a similar problem. I'm not sure, but it could be because of `keyOne` being considered differently combined with duck typing. Could you try using the value key syntax and a string literal? Like `["key"] = value`?

Comment: @Random Interesting. Yeah, I tried it using the string literal syntax for the key/value pairs like `['keyOne'] = { a = 'hello' }` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I've just tested it myself and it seems like what I said wasn't the case. For example, instead of omitting `b`, give it a value like `nil`, `1` or `true`; and it displays a type error. Using a variable makes it work normally. This could be a bug.

Comment: Someone just opened [an issue](https://github.com/Roblox/luau/issues/655), in case that wasn't you.

Comment: @Random You're right, I also noticed that before posting the initial question. I spoke to someone about this behavior and they opened that github issue for it. I appreciate the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in current Luau (0.545 as of this writing in September 2022), once you have an indexer (`[string]`) in your type, the rest of the keys on the type will not be checked in the way you expect.

Using indexers can definitely be a nice ergonomic improvement over explicit method calls, but besides the type system not quite giving the safety you want in those cases, it can sometimes be *slower* than the explicit method call approach.

When overriding __index, __newindex, and/or __call on tables for better ergonomics, make sure you aren't unknowingly opting out of type safety, or increasing runtime overhead in the hot path of your Luau application.